# How to enable OpenLDAP log on CentOS 6.4

Tags: openldap

I have installed OpenLDAP 2.4.23 on CentOS 6.4. Default install.

OpenLDAP does not seem to create any log information. At times it is convient to have some information on what OpenLDAP is doing.

How can logging be enabled/configured?

Answer (score 0):

By default, OpenLDAP logs all information to syslog's local4 facility.

Add the following line to **/etc/syslog.conf**:

```
local4.*                        /var/log/ldap.log
```

Restart the syslog service and check out this log.